# Lambda in SFML C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to lambda's in general. Down to business:
I'm using SFML library to make a game. To create a window in sfml you can use this code:

```cpp
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "Its about power");
        window.setFramerateLimit(60);
        while (window.isOpen()) {
            // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
                // "close requested" event: we close the window
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
                if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
                {
                    cout << "pressed" << endl;
                }
            }

            // clear the window with black color
            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            // draw everything here...

            // end the current frame
            window.display();
        }
```

Now you see, i want to try to make this code into a function and leave only the events and drawings of the objects as code i can change. Thats where lambda's and such come in:
I want the code to look something like this in main():

```cpp
Aclass Game;
Game.window([] (sf::Event &ev)
{
     //Would have events for the game here, eg 'if button pressed'
     if (ev.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed){}
},[] (Aclass &g)
{
     //Would have place to draw the game objects here
     g.window.draw(g.button1);
});
```

And here's my code that doesn't work:
(For some reason it keeps not responding. it draws the first frame and then stops responding)

```cpp
//Classes:
class Window1
{
public:
    sf::RenderWindow window = sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "Its about power");
    sf::RectangleShape rect;
    Window1()
    {
        rect.setSize({300, 200});
    }

    void windowOpen(void (*x)(sf::Event&), void (*y)(void))
    {
        window.setFramerateLimit(60);
        while (window.isOpen()) {
            // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
            sf::Event event;
            x(event);
            // clear the window with black color
            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            // draw everything here...
            y();
            //window.draw(rect);

            // end the current frame
            window.display();
        }
    }

};

class Screen1
{
public:
    sf::RectangleShape rect2;
    sf::CircleShape cir1;
    Screen1()
    {
        rect2.setSize({100, 50});
        rect2.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
        cir1.setRadius(15);
        cir1.setPosition(300, 400);
    }
};

class Game : public Window1
{
public:
    Screen1 s1;
    Screen1 s2;
    void windowOpen(void (*x)(sf::Event&), void (*y)(Game&))
    {
        window.setFramerateLimit(60);
        while (window.isOpen()) {
            // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
            sf::Event event;
            x(event);
            // clear the window with black color
            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            // draw everything here...
            y(*this);
            //window.draw(rect);

            // end the current frame
            window.display();
        }
    }
};

//main()

int main()
{
    Game g;
    g.windowOpen([](sf::Event &event)
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) cout << "pressed" << endl;

    },[](Game &g)
    {
        g.window.draw(g.s1.cir1);
        g.window.draw(g.s1.rect2);
    });
return 0;
}
```

Also as an additional side question: How does one capture 'this' in the lamda's in this instance. i tried doing it in many different ways but it always ended up giving me some error.

Comment: You're updated lambda version doesn't seem to call `pollEvent`

Comment: Thank you. @zdan . Btw is there a way to have the variable that is sent over through the lambda interchangable? like i want to draw any variable inside the class Game, to do that i need to send the Game object to the function. If i wanted to use this class in inheritance, will the variables in that other class that i inherit into, will also pop up in the lambda function even if i just use the Game object? if no, how would i be able to do that?